Transparent material turns black when exported to GLB/GLTF
I'm putting a label on a beer bottle. The label in the back is supposed to be transparent with white text, and it is in Blender. When I export to GLTF/GLB the label is black with white text. I've researched everywhere online and tried different solutions but nothing seems to work. I've tried different blend modes and shadow modes, everythings UV-mapped etc.. If you have any idea I'd appreciate the help ALOT! Also, I just feel like the bottle doesn't look at all as good when exported as it does in Blender, so if anyone has an input there too I'd appreciate it!





https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

I'd expect the exporter to combine the base color and alpha textures at export, but it looks like it could be failing to do so correctly. It may help if you can combine those two textures into a single RGBA texture instead.
To get a better appearance on the glass, I would look for a glTF viewer that offers a choice of HDRI environments. Would also test "transmission" instead of alpha blending, if you aren't already.

The glTF exporter should be able to handle this, I think.  I wonder if the alpha-clip material appearing in front of a transmission material is the problem?  What's the final render, ThreeJS or similar?  I'm suspicious that there's some order-of-render issue between the two different materials.
